# How to merge only a few change to another branch

Tags: git, moodle

I did a clone of Moodle and I did local changes to customize the code. Now, I want to update to the latest version of Moodle (2.7) and I want to merge my changes. Moodle have a lot of changes so I want to do it as automaticly as possible.

So, by default I want the official version, from the Moodle repo, except for 4 files. I have only 3 commits I added to the previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing), which is like saying "take all these changes and pretend they were actually done on *this* commit, instead".

Comment: It works but there a lot of change and merge all diffierences is too long. There is maybe 450 commits and to rebase ask me to merge manually files with differiences. Do you have a tip to go faster?

Comment: If the underlying files change in such a way that Git's merging strategy can't figure out how to put your changes back on top, then your only option is to manually merge the files. You might want to look at making your project a [Moodle plugin](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Main_Page), instead.

Comment: I think to use a vim plugin like fugitive can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a minor moodle version, you can usually just merge in changes and it will work.

If it is a major moodle version (e.g. 2.5 to 2.6), then the advice I've followed multiple times (with some heavily customised customer sites), can be found on Tim Hunt's blog: http://tjhunt.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/moving-ou-moodle-code-to-moodle-261.html

A few other bits of advice. Avoid core changes if possible, you can do many things with plugins and theme renderers. Put clear comments around and required core changes. Don't use rebase if you've pushed your code anywhere else (e.g. to a live site, or another developer) - it is only ever useful if you are preparing changes, before merging back into a main code branch.